# How to store an object together with a notification so that I can call it when receiving the notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, localnotification

I am new to programming and this is my very first project. I am making a pretty simple reminder app; I've created a class reminder with the properties .moreInformation (String), .fireDate (Date), .fromDate (Date), .title (String) and .image(UIImage). You can edit all these properties within in the application. My problem is just: I need a proper solution for storing this object 'reminder'. I am using UserNotifications to register my notification like that:

```
reminder.fireDate = date
    reminder.image = image
    reminder.description = descriptionTextView.text
    reminder.title = titleTextView.text
    reminder.savedOndate = savedOnDateString

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "General", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    let contentText = reminder.savedOnDate
    content.title = "Reminder"
    content.body = "Your Reminder from the \(contentText) has arrived!"

    let date2 = reminder.fireDate
    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: date2)

    components.hour = 18
    components.minute = 0

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)


    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

When the user has received the notification, he should see a pop-up view when starting the app, leading him to a separate view controller that shows the description text, the fromDate etc.

But how do I store the object together with the notification so when the notification has arrived, the other view controller shows the correct description text/ title etc.?

Comment: could you please write the solution so others can get help from you question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `userInfo` dictionary of your `UNMutableNotificationContent` instance to store custom information.
Keep in mind that objects stored in the `userInfo` dictionary must be property-list types. This means you either need to convert your `reminder` object to such a type (e.g. `NSDictionary`) or, and this would be a cleaner solution, implement `NSCoding` in the class of the `reminder` object and en/decode it using `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: and how do I call it after having received the notification?

Comment: The `UNNotification` object you'll receive has a `request` property of the type `UNNotificationRequest` which has a `content` property of the type `UNNotificationContent` that contains your `userInfo` dictionary. You can learn more about notifications in [Session 707](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/) and [Session 708](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/) from last year's WWDC.